R Markdown Code Folding Button Text Discrepency (Rbloggers vs Mine)
There is an example of R Markdown code folding on Rbloggers.
Here is the example R Markdown file content:
---
title: "Code Collapse Demonstration"
output:
  html_document:
    code_folding: hide
---

```{r}
#| include = FALSE
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

There is a negative correlation between horsepower and miles per gallon.

```{r}
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point()
```

On their site the output looks like this:

But when I knit the R Markdown example, my output looks like this:

Why is the button labeled differently between the Rbloggers (i.e., "Code") and mine (i.e., "Show")? And how could I get the text of my button to be "Code" as in the example (or even better "Show Code")?

Why did the button text change?
The text of the button has changed because those examples on R-bloggers were run using a version of {rmarkdown} before this commit, and your code was run using a version of {rmarkdown} after the commit.
This change was made because:

When code folding is enabled in html_document(), the text on the button to show the content has been changed from "Code" to "Show", because the content to show is not necessarily code, e.g., yihui/knitr#2227.

How can I get the same functionality?
Here are four options.
Option 1: Post-process your HTML file
After knitting run the following script against your knitted HTML output file to read, make the necessary edits, and overwrite your HTML file.
html_file_name <- "my_knitted_file.html"

readLines(html_file_name) |>
  sub(
    pattern     = "var showCodeText = $('<span>' + (showThis ? 'Hide' : 'Show') + '</span>');", 
    replacement = "var showCodeText = $('<span>' + (showThis ? 'Hide Code' : 'Show Code') + '</span>');",
    fixed = TRUE
  ) |>
  sub(
    pattern     = "showCodeText.text('Show');",
    replacement = "showCodeText.text('Show Code');",
    fixed = TRUE
  ) |>
  sub(
    pattern     = "showCodeText.text('Hide');",
    replacement = "showCodeText.text('Hide Code');",
    fixed = TRUE
  ) |>
  writeLines(html_file_name)


Option 2: Edit your installed codefolding.js
Before knitting run this script to overwrite your installed codefolding.js file. Note, this change will be overwritten the next time you install {rmarkdown}.
codefolding_js_file_path <- system.file("Rmd/h/navigation-1.1/codefolding.js", package = "rmarkdown")

codefolding_js_file_path |>
  readLines() |>
  sub(
    pattern     = "var showCodeText = $('<span>' + (showThis ? 'Hide' : 'Show') + '</span>');",
    replacement = "var showCodeText = $('<span>' + (showThis ? 'Hide Code' : 'Show Code') + '</span>');",
    fixed = TRUE
  ) |>
  sub(
    pattern     = "showCodeText.text('Show');",
    replacement = "showCodeText.text('Show Code');",
    fixed = TRUE
  ) |>
  sub(
    pattern     = "showCodeText.text('Hide');",
    replacement = "showCodeText.text('Hide Code');",
    fixed = TRUE
  ) |>
  writeLines(codefolding_js_file_path)


Option 3: Install an earlier version of {rmarkdown}
Before knitting you can get matching functionality to the Rblogger site by installing a corresponding version of {rmarkdown}.
packageurl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rmarkdown/rmarkdown_2.21.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos = NULL, type = "source")


Option 4: Fork the {rmarkdown} source
Before knitting you could fork the {rmarkdown} source code, make the labeling changes, and install your forked version. An example of this is available here.
remotes::install_github("the-mad-statter/rmarkdown")



Many thanks for both answers, but the proposed solutions are all far too complicated for an average user of rmarkdown. I think that the bottom of the problem is that the reason argued for the commit is wrong, as what the user wants to show in most cases is code. Thus, the solution provided by the commit for the few cases in which code is not what is intended to show, is actually worse than the original problem. The real solution would be a simple user-friendly way to select the text in the button and, meanwhile, go back to the "code" text.
